# Getting Mount Points using awk & grep

Tags: parsing, awk, command-line, windows-subsystem-for-linux, mount-point

I am trying to get mount points and their respective paths on linux. So when I run the `mount -v` command I get this example output

```
//cifst/FSR on /mnt/share/cifst/FSR type cifs ...
//sydatsttbsq01/TheBooks statements to be parsed on /mnt/share/TheBooks type cifs ...
```

I am trying to parse this text to display this output

```
/mnt/share/cifst/FSR;//cifst/FSR
/mnt/share/TheBooks;//sydatsttbsq01/TheBooks
```

But the `/mnt` on the first row is in column 3, while on the second row is in column 5 so how do I do this to get the `/mnt` part

`mount -v | grep mnt | awk '{ print $1'}` gets me the path but how do I get the mount points.

Comment: Don't use paths with spaces?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: The share name `TheBooks statements to be parsed` ...

Comment: Can you try this instead of mount command? `df -h | awk '{ print $NF";"$1}'`

Answer (score 0):

For this particular output something like this will work; bear in mind that it will break if any of the paths with spaces that you use have the word "on" in them.

```
mount -v | awk 'BEGIN{FS="( on | type )"; OFS=";"} $3 ~ /cifs/ {print $2,$1}'
/mnt/share/cifst/FSR;//cifst/FSR
/mnt/share/TheBooks;//sydatsttbsq01/TheBooks statements to be parsed
```

P.S.: You'd be *much* better off if you didn't use spaces in paths, replace them with `.`, or `_`, or camelcase them ...

Comment: Then your sample output above doesn't match what you have on your system.

Comment: Yes I do. I have just been running it on my computer. Either you have a different version of awk or something else. Also for the paths its just `//sydatsttbsq01/TheBooks` the bit after that is not part of the path.

Comment: It *is* part of the path, otherwise it wouldn't show up before the " on ". It's certainly not part of mount's output.  As for awk - what version are you using?  I'm using `gawk 5.0.1`

Comment: I am using GNU Awk 5.0.1

Comment: Same awk then ... what Linux version are you running?

Comment: I am using Windows SubSystem for Linux.

Comment: WSL is notoriously bad w/ copy & pasting commands ... try TYPING what I wrote.

Comment: I checked it copied exactly as you wrote. `awk 'BEGIN{FS="( on | type )"; OFS=";"}$3=="cifs"{print $2,$1}'`

Comment: Think character substitution.  It may *look* the same.

Comment: OK, so here it's not encoding, it's a bug in `awk` in WSL. I tried this on a windows box, and it's not printing anything because the `$3=="cifs"` is failing in WSL.  What **should** work just fine doesn't. If we replace the `==` with a regex match it works on windows, too. @Ishan - looks like WSL sucks.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of assumptions, but this works for your sample input/output:

```
$ cat << EOF | awk '{print $(NF-2), $1}' OFS=\;
> //cifst/FSR on /mnt/share/cifst/FSR type cifs
> //sydatsttbsq01/TheBooks statements to be parsed on /mnt/share/TheBooks type cifs
> EOF
/mnt/share/cifst/FSR;//cifst/FSR
/mnt/share/TheBooks;//sydatsttbsq01/TheBooks
```

The trick is to notice that it's not column 3 and 5 you're interested in, but in each case it is column NF - 2.

In this particular case, the `grep` is redundant because it matches each line of input, and in general `grep` is (almost) always redundant with `awk`.  If you need to add the filter, do it with awk and use:

```
awk '/mnt/{print $(NF-2), $1}' OFS=\;
```

Comment: I updated the output in the question. There are a long line of text after `type cifs` on each line. I have used ... to indicate that. So what you suggested wont work.

Answer (score 0):

If the fields you are interested in are #1 and the next after the first field equal to "`on`", and they do not contain spaces, you could try this:

```
mount -v | awk '{a="";for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){if(a=="on")break;a=$i};print $i";"$1}'
```

If we add one more hypothesis that there is only one field equal to "`on`", another possibility is to use `gensub`:

```
mount -v | awk '{print gensub(/^(\S+).*\<on\>\s+(\S+).*/,"\\2;\\1",1)}'
```

Which brings us to a sed equivalent:

```
mount -v | sed -r 's/^(\S+).*\<on\>\s+(\S+).*/\2;\1/'
```